# What is the normal way to send crash reports, product registrations, etc in C++?

Tags: c++, windows, communication

What is the normal way to send crash reports, product registrations, etc?  In other words, how do you guarantee your C++ Windows apps can 'call home'?

I'm not a novice by any means but I'm completely lost in this area.  I've never done it before so would appreciate any advice.

Kind Regards,

Answer (score 4):

For crash reports I would strongly recommend taking advantage of Microsoft's [WinQual](https://winqual.microsoft.com/) service rather than attempting to create your own. It's free and seamlessly integrated with Windows, at least since XP. It also requires no code or client-side changes at all at its most basic level. To take advantage of more advanced features you can use the [Windows Error Reporting](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb513641(VS.85).aspx) APIs.

Answer (score 3):

Code I've written simply creates an email with the required information using the users default email application with information in plain text. I **always** get the permission of the user to send it, explaining clearly why I think the information is necessary. Nothing is sent without their express permission.

I also prefer to use plain text (not alway possible with memory dumps and such) so they can check what's being sent and no personal or identifying information.

I'm very careful with that stuff since there are possible legal implications with doing it, at least in the jurisdiction where I operate. In any case, it should always be done with the users permission as a matter of courtesy.

Answer (score 0):

As far as crash reporting is concerned, there's [WER](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Windows_Error_Reporting) for starters. It has its drawbacks (the biggest being you have to sign up for it at microsoft and all reports are sent to a central microsoft server) and is best for driver software.

If you need anything else (add your own wishes here), you can either roll your own solution (codeproject.com search provides a few alternatives - just go "crash report").

Regarding product registration - there must be 3rd party solution available as well. I have not heard of anything "built-in" for that, but it is a vast topic - you have to be more specific on features you're after.